# How to parse date string with this input 2019-08-06 08:26:17

Tags: android

I want to parse the date but this happen:

Unparseable date: " 2019-08-06 08:26:17" (at offset 0)

```
  try {
            String string = " 2019-08-06 08:26:17";
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  hh:mm a");
            Date date = format.parse(string);
            Log.d("datesssss", date.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.d("datessssError", e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: You have an extra space at the beginning of your date string

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  hh:mm a");
    String eDate ="2019-08-06 08:26:17";
    Date eDDte;
    try {
        eDDte = df2.parse(eDate);
        System.out.println("Date: " + df3.format(eDDte));
    } catch(ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: it will just return a default date

Comment: Just now noticed the month is not correct. The df2 format should be changed to ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
        String stringDate= " 2019-08-06 08:26:17";
        stringDate = ltrim(stringDate);
        stringDate = rtrim(stringDate);
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy  hh:mm a");
        Date date = format.parse(stringDate);
        Log.d("datesssss", date.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.d("datessssError", e.toString());
    }
```